# ActionBarSherlock + GoogleMaps v2 map not shown (without map log errors)

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android-maps-v2, actionbarsherlock-map

I just settled my project for supporting Android Maps v2 + ActionBarSherlock, as this answer says:

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/13727539/689723

Ok, I was fighting for not getting the typical XML error, and I could finally get the fragment without errors.

I'm pretty sure my AndroidManifest is ok.

My log is:

```
01-21 00:43:03.455: D/dalvikvm(4990): GC_CONCURRENT freed 311K, 8% free 13870K/14983K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 20ms
01-21 00:43:03.455: D/dalvikvm(4990): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
01-21 00:43:03.555: D/dalvikvm(4990): GC_CONCURRENT freed 379K, 7% free 14100K/15047K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 32ms
01-21 00:43:03.555: D/dalvikvm(4990): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
01-21 00:43:03.555: D/dalvikvm(4990): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
01-21 00:43:03.555: D/dalvikvm(4990): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
01-21 00:43:03.555: D/dalvikvm(4990): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
01-21 00:43:03.555: D/dalvikvm(4990): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
01-21 00:43:03.555: D/dalvikvm(4990): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
01-21 00:43:03.555: D/dalvikvm(4990): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
01-21 00:43:03.555: D/dalvikvm(4990): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
01-21 00:43:03.555: D/dalvikvm(4990): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
01-21 00:43:03.560: E/System(4990): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
01-21 00:43:03.560: E/System(4990): java.io.IOException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
01-21 00:43:03.560: E/System(4990):     at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:41)
01-21 00:43:03.560: E/System(4990):     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.close(RandomAccessFile.java:166)
01-21 00:43:03.560: E/System(4990):     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.finalize(RandomAccessFile.java:175)
01-21 00:43:03.560: E/System(4990):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:186)
01-21 00:43:03.560: E/System(4990):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)
01-21 00:43:03.560: E/System(4990):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-21 00:43:03.560: E/System(4990): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
01-21 00:43:03.560: E/System(4990):     at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
01-21 00:43:03.560: E/System(4990):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
01-21 00:43:03.560: E/System(4990):     at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:38)
01-21 00:43:03.560: E/System(4990):     ... 5 more
01-21 00:43:03.630: D/dalvikvm(4990): GC_CONCURRENT freed 487K, 7% free 14299K/15367K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 29ms
01-21 00:43:03.630: D/dalvikvm(4990): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
01-21 00:43:03.635: D/AbsListView(4990): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-21 00:43:03.670: D/SensorManager(4990): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41d803c0
01-21 00:43:03.670: D/Sensors(4990): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
01-21 00:43:03.670: I/Sensors(4990): sendDelay --- 200000000
01-21 00:43:03.670: D/SensorManager(4990): JNI - sendDelay
01-21 00:43:03.670: I/SensorManager(4990): Set normal delay = true
01-21 00:43:03.800: D/dalvikvm(4990): GC_CONCURRENT freed 291K, 6% free 14721K/15623K, paused 13ms+15ms, total 54ms
01-21 00:43:03.875: D/dalvikvm(4990): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 653K, 10% free 14731K/16199K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
01-21 00:43:03.955: D/dalvikvm(4990): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 642K, 10% free 14730K/16199K, paused 23ms, total 24ms
01-21 00:43:03.965: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4990): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
01-21 00:43:03.970: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4990): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

But I think the I/O error is not related to maps...

This is an screenshot[image]

Anyone knows what's happening here?

Thanks in advance,

César.

**STATUS: SOLVED**

Api key problem. For more info:

[Google Maps Android v2 Authorization failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757362/google-maps-android-v2-authorization-failure/14434593#14434593)

Comment: SOLVED

It was problem of the API key.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757362/google-maps-android-v2-authorization-failure/14434593#14434593

Comment: hi,can you have a working example that you can send me?
I am trying to do the same of you but I have still problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951624/actionbarsherlock-google-maps-not-showing-tiles

thanks in advance