# Actionbarsherlock Google Maps not showing tiles

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, actionbarsherlock-map

I am trying to get a Google Map with a static actionbarsherlock. I have done it but the map is not loaded (no tiles are loaded). I am sure that my Google Map key is correct, and I don't know what is the problem.

Can you help me?
In the zip file there is my little project.

http://www.michelepierri.it/DEMOCHOOSER.zip

this is my code:

MapSimple.java

```
package com.actionbarsherlock.sample.maps;

import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app2.SherlockMapActivity;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MapSimple extends SherlockMapActivity {
    ActionBarSherlock mSherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //MapView for the lose :(
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.map_warning, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        setContentView(R.layout.map_simple);
        MapView mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mSherlock.setUiOptions(ActivityInfo.UIOPTION_SPLIT_ACTION_BAR_WHEN_NARROW);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Used to put dark icons on light action bar

        menu.add("Save")
            .setIcon( R.drawable.ic_compose)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        menu.add("Search")
            .setIcon( R.drawable.ic_search)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        menu.add("Refresh")
            .setIcon( R.drawable.ic_refresh)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        return true;
    }
}
```

DemoChooser.java

```
    /*
 * Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.actionbarsherlock.sample.maps;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity;

import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DemoChooser extends SherlockListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String path = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.android.apis.Path");

        if (path == null) {
            path = "";
        }

        setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, getData(path),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "title" },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

    protected List<Map<String, Object>> getData(String prefix) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> myData = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory("com.actionbarsherlock.sample.plugins.MAPS");

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

        if (null == list)
            return myData;

        String[] prefixPath;
        String prefixWithSlash = prefix;

        if (prefix.equals("")) {
            prefixPath = null;
        } else {
            prefixPath = prefix.split("/");
            prefixWithSlash = prefix + "/";
        }

        int len = list.size();

        Map<String, Boolean> entries = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            ResolveInfo info = list.get(i);
            CharSequence labelSeq = info.loadLabel(pm);
            String label = labelSeq != null
                    ? labelSeq.toString()
                    : info.activityInfo.name;

            if (prefixWithSlash.length() == 0 || label.startsWith(prefixWithSlash)) {

                String[] labelPath = label.split("/");

                String nextLabel = prefixPath == null ? labelPath[0] : labelPath[prefixPath.length];

                if ((prefixPath != null ? prefixPath.length : 0) == labelPath.length - 1) {
                    addItem(myData, nextLabel, activityIntent(
                            info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
                            info.activityInfo.name));
                } else {
                    if (entries.get(nextLabel) == null) {
                        addItem(myData, nextLabel, browseIntent(prefix.equals("") ? nextLabel : prefix + "/" + nextLabel));
                        entries.put(nextLabel, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(myData, sDisplayNameComparator);

        return myData;
    }

    private final static Comparator<Map<String, Object>> sDisplayNameComparator =
        new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {
        private final Collator   collator = Collator.getInstance();

        public int compare(Map<String, Object> map1, Map<String, Object> map2) {
            return collator.compare(map1.get("title"), map2.get("title"));
        }
    };

    protected Intent activityIntent(String pkg, String componentName) {
        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.setClassName(pkg, componentName);
        return result;
    }

    protected Intent browseIntent(String path) {
        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.setClass(this, DemoChooser.class);
        result.putExtra("com.example.android.apis.Path", path);
        return result;
    }

    protected void addItem(List<Map<String, Object>> data, String name, Intent intent) {
        Map<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        temp.put("title", name);
        temp.put("intent", intent);
        data.add(temp);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>)l.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Intent intent = (Intent) map.get("intent");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```